# Access Bootloader on VSD241

Tags: bootloader

I'm trying to access the Bootloader on a Viewsonic VSD241, but the menu that comes up tells me to hit the "volume up" button to select Bootloader from the menu. There are no hard volume control options on this tablet, so I was wondering if anyone had an idea for what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an alternative route, have you tried using `ADB` in your PC? `adb reboot bootloader` command can boot you straight into your device's bootloader.

Comment: I did try that. The tablet shuts down, but won't come back up until I hit the power button. When it does, I still end up at the menu that asks me to hit the volume button.

Comment: This model has regular usb ports. Perhaps plugging in a USB multimedia keyboard would work to control the *volume buttons*. [This page](http://paperlined.org/apps/android/hardware_keyboard.html) suggests that multimedia keys on a PC keyboard are equivalent to the volume buttons.